# Submit a certain button when ENTER is pressed

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, django-templates

I have a web page with one form and many buttons.
I want to submit a POST for the search button when the user presses ENTER in the search textbox where the POST holds the name of the search button.

I have seen many solutions to submit a POST of a form, but none of them told me how to include the search button within the form POST.

This is a simplified version of the code:

The template:

```
<form name="form" id="form" action="" method="POST">
    <input type="text" id="txtbx_search" name="txtbox_search"> 

    <button id="btn_print" type="submit" name="btn_print"><b>Print</b> </button>

    <button id="btn_delete" type="submit" name="btn_delete"><b> Delete</b> </button>

    <button id="btn_search" type="submit" name="btn_search"><b>Search</b> </button>

    {% csrf_token %}

</form>
```

My views:

```
if request.method == POST:
        if 'btn_search' in request.POST:
            # Do my search
```

I have tried this way:

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#txtbx_search').keypress(function (e) {
                if (e.keyCode == 13) {
                    e.preventDefault();

                    document.getElementById('btn_search').click();
                    //OR
                    document.getElementById('form').submit();
                }
            });
        });

</script>
```

But how can I include the button within the POST data?
By default, when I press ENTER, the print button is submitted
Thank you very much.

Comment: Hi, is this code submitting ? Do you need to click btn_search just before submit ?

Comment: use tabindex  and try.

Comment: Submitting a form is a default behavior when focus is inside input element and `enter` is pressed..

Comment: The document.getElementById('form').submit(); is submitting but the click doesn't that's why I said OR because I tried them both.
The document.getElementById('form').submit(); submits but the POST data doesn't have the 'btn_search'

Comment: @Rayon Yea, but how can I move the focus to another button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this myself and managed to make it work the following way.

```
<form id="importForm" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div class="row" style="text-align:center">
                <button id="importButton" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="btn-hello">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-upload" aria-hidden="true"></span> Import
            </button>

                <button id="importButton2" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="btn-byebye">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-upload" aria-hidden="true"></span> Import
            </button>
            </div>

</form>
```

The script posts 'btn-hello' to the backend as expected. I also changed #importButton to #importButton2 and it posted 'btn-byebye'.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('body').keypress(function (e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 13) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $("#importButton").click();
        }
    });
});
```

Perhaps the fault in your code lies in    document.getElementById('btn_search').click();. Try to use $("#btn_search").click();